# Family sharing - ask to buy

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, family-sharing

I'm unclear what the default setting is regarding 'ask to buy' settings for family sharing and a child’s AppleID.

If I do NOT enable 'ask to buy' am I right to assume that my daughter will be unable to buy anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best write up for setting up children accounts is here:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201084

> If you turn off Ask to Buy, your child can buy content with your payment method without asking you first.

Your daughter can spend down your default payment method using your money if you turn off **Ask to Buy**.

Comment: Thanks.  Without me doing anything, the default setting was 'ask to buy' is NOT enabled.  I understand you to say unless I enable 'ask to buy' my daughter can buy things freely without me knowing...?

Comment: You get to see later her purchases but not impede them in any way @dan - Apple says they default to Organizer approval for children under 13 * , but you’d have to work with their support if you feel that didn’t happen on your specific account. I’m guessing that setting is very thoroughly logged since it’s about money and minors.

Comment: Hmm - seems the wrong way round!  I need proactively to enable 'ask to buy' to have control of my purse.